How can I make my next app responsive on iPhone?
I've made a webpage using nextjs which is responsive using media queries, works really well on safari using mac and at Firefox as well.
but when I try to open it on iPhone the images have a completely different size and media queries appear to do not work. its like it just run all media queries instead of only the ones according to the window size.
I tried adding the meta tag at layout.tsx but that did not work either.
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import "./globals.css";

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Migra",
  description: "Encontre o melhor lugar para trabalhar/viajar",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
      </head>
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}

